# Complete beginner. Where should I start?

Tags: book-recommendation

I completed my high school recently. Throughout my middle and high school years math was a subject I feared and avoided. So I never ***learned*** any math throughout that period. I just memorized what I had to and passed the exams. Now that I have some time, I would like to learn mathematics from the very basics to college level math.

I want to truly understand math. But I don’t know where to start this journey.

Comment: I wish I had started out by reading some history of math books.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be something of interest to you or not but I might recommend Morris Kline's [Mathematics for the Nonmathematician](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Nonmathematician-Dover-Books-ebook/dp/B00BX1DN9K). Although it's target audience might be more for liberal arts students, I found it to be a good reference for helping me explain mathematical concepts easier to students when I worked as a tutor in college. Plus it's hard to argue the price.

Comment: You don't have to commit to any particular book. Look at a lot of books and see which ones connect with you. I haven't read or looked at this book, but I've heard that Gelfand's book [Algebra](https://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Israel-M-Gelfand/dp/0817636773/ref=pd_aw_fbt_img_2/143-6854653-5226928?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=0817636773&pd_rd_r=7791a075-938e-45e5-ad05-f2f42d05e4ef&pd_rd_w=F39zp&pd_rd_wg=g11bg&pf_rd_p=e5143995-bc4c-4e22-9b66-79eb4d8ad240&pf_rd_r=Q3N149WP0FDAVG8XBJ3E&psc=1&refRID=Q3N149WP0FDAVG8XBJ3E) is a good book on high school algebra.

Comment: Suggestion: Basic Mathematics, by Lang.

Comment: You should start with Euclid's Elements. https://archive.org/details/tayloreuclid00euclrich/page/n29/mode/2up